# Find a function $f$ and a number $a$ such that $3 + ∫_a^x \frac{f(t)}t\,dt = \sqrt x$ for all $x>0$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find a function $f$ and a number $a$ such that $3 + ∫_a^x \frac{f(t)}t\,dt = \sqrt x$ for all $x>0$

I was thinking of using Leibniz's rule but I don't know where to start with $t$ and $f(t)$. I assume the FTOC plays into this, but for whatever reason the $t$ in the denominator is throwing me off.

Comment: Please improve your post by including everything in there and by adding what you have tried do.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I was thinking of using Leibniz's rule but I don't know where to start with t and f(t)

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly. Not everyone checks the comments.

Comment: oh ok makes sense thanks shaun :)

Comment: thank you andrew!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just assume that $f$ is continuous and defined on some closed interval $[a, b]$ (where $a$ is the $a$ from the question). Furthermore, let's assume that $a > 0,$ so that $$\frac{f(t)}{t}$$ is also defined on the interval $[a, b]$ (and continuous on that interval, too).

Let $F \colon [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined so that
$$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} \frac{f(t)}{t} \mathrm{d}t.$$ By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we have
$$F'(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$$.

On the other hand, we have
$$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} \frac{f(t)}{t} \mathrm{d}t = \sqrt{x} -3,$$ hence we have
$$F'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}.$$ So, it follows that we have
$$\frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}.$$ We see that we must have
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x}.$$

Now, let's find an $a$ so that for all $x > 0,$ we have
$$\sqrt{x} = 3 + \int_{a}^{x} \frac{f(t)}{t} \mathrm{d}t.$$ We have
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x} &= 3 + \int_{a}^{x} \frac{f(t)}{t} \mathrm{d}t\\
&= 3 + \int_{a}^{x} \frac{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{t}}{t} \mathrm{d}t\\
&= 3 + \int_{a}^{x} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}} \mathrm{d}t\\
&= 3 + (\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a})
\end{align*}

So, we see that $3 - \sqrt{a} = 0,$ hence we have $a = 9.$

To conclude, it suffices to take $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x}$ and $a = 9.$

Comment: Thank you so much!!